# How do propeller planes suddenly make noise?

Tags: propeller, engine

I was wondering: how can a propeller plane, single engine or otherwise, be flying along relatively silently and then start making noise, often very loud--and then turn it off just as quickly? Are they descending/ascending? It seems like the engine must be straining.
Thank you.

Comment: Engine noise is a very small portion of the total noise of a propeller (or rotor) aircraft. Propeller tip speed seems more likely to me to be a determining factor, especially as the propeller tips approach the transsonic region.

Comment: When flying or when taxiing?

Comment: When flying overhead...I see planes that are able to turn the noise on or off--without appearing to be making dramatic movements.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you're close to an airport with a lot of flight training, you may be hearing aircraft [in the pattern](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25763/62) making power changes as they take off at high/full power then reduce it again for landing.

Answer (score 9):

It is unusual to change prop speed quickly and only briefly, so I would suggest two possible explanations:

1. **On the ground:** The pilot tests the propeller pitch control. This he/she does by revving up the engine while the propeller is at a low pitch setting. Then the pitch is increased, which increases the aerodynamic forces on the prop and, consequently, the noise it radiates out. Since this test takes only a few seconds, the result is just what you described (but not while flying overhead).
2. **In the air:** Propellers don't radiate noise equally in all directions. This is especially pronounced on the [T-6 "Texan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan), where the noise intensity increases dramatically when you stand directly abeam of the aircraft. The plot below is taken from [this](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/779773.pdf) report on propeller noise. Probably what you hear is caused by the variation in noise (and dominant frequencies) while the plane flies overhead.

[image: Directivity plot of propeller noise]

Directivity plot of propeller noise. The details depend a lot on the specific aircraft and propeller type.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the noise of a propeller plane comes from the propeller tips. And an easy way to change the noise is to change the tip-speed, either suddenly up, suddenly down, or gently.

People on the ground notice the *change* in the noise of an airplane, so if you need to change the propeller speed, it's best to do this gently so there's no sudden 'whoosh' of the tips.

Answer (score -1):

It could simply be that the plane is passing you at a high-ish speed, at a high altitude. The plane is high up and moving fast, and it takes a second for the sound to hit you, The you hear the sound and the plane is gone, then the sound cuts out.

Comment: It could be... but then again, it could be a lot of things.